# Jquery Dynamically generated buttons no css

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am fetching some data from a Google Places Api, I am using jquerymobile to show a user nearest places, the data comes in JSON I want to generate a set of buttons so is easy for user to click selected location.

The data is generated but the button is showed as a link with no style, even is the same code of another button with style. here is the code snippet.

```
$.each(pdata.results, function(key) { 
    if (key>0 && key<6) {
$('#dPlaces').append('<a href="#" data-role="button">'+pdata.results[key].name+'</a>');                  
} //endif
}); //each
```

Data is returned but no Button style.. the idea is I will put a onclick() to set some value and way a list of buttons but with JQM style.

thanks.

Norman

Comment: can you show the other button code you're referring to as well as the css that should be applied to these links?

Comment: may be you need to render not `<a>` but `<button>` or `<input type='button'>` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh the page, try something like this:

```
$.each(pdata.results, function(key) { 
    if (key>0 && key<6) {
        $('#dPlaces').append('<a href="#" data-role="button">'+pdata.results[key].name+'</a>').page();                  
    } //endif
});
```

or maybe:

```
$.each(pdata.results, function(key) { 
    if (key>0 && key<6) {
        $('#dPlaces').append('<a href="#" data-role="button">'+pdata.results[key].name+'</a>');                  
    } //endif
});

$('#dPlaces').page();
```

UPDATE:

```
$('div').live('pageshow',function(event, ui){
    $.each(pdata.results, function(key) { 
        if (key>0 && key<6) {
            $('#dPlaces').append('<a href="#" data-role="button">'+pdata.results[key].name+'</a>');                  
        } //endif
    });

    $('#dPlaces').page();
});
```

Docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/api/events.html

Comment: Thanks the $('#dPlaces').page(); after the loop worked, but something weird is that the 2nd time it does not work as desired :-/

Comment: you may need to add it to a .live()  http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/api/events.html

Comment: You mean, add the .Page() to the live()? I changed to be used with simple <p>My text</p> and a </hr> to divide.. but will like to test with buttons, thanks..

Comment: if you're transitioning to a new page you need to encapsulate the code above inside a .live event. See update